# A wired idea: Are there any Chinese idioms dictionary which is specific to translate a English word?

Tags: dictionary

I wonder to enhance my rhetoric on my English. The Chinese classical idioms are elegance words to be a word to represent anything. To contrast, it is a word as adj. or adv. in English. Maybe there are some words hard to use one word to explain in all. But, I think it is not completely to translate every words in the idiom dictionary.(i.e. It is not possible to translate every words due to some words hard to be translate.) Anyway, I think it is good for Chinese-English communication. Because one word can represent anything that is simple and should be explicit. For an instance, the English word "serendipity", is meaning a lucky encounter on seeing a good things. In Chinese, I will translate to be "如獲至寶".

In the derivate on making a book, I think it should include the possibility  or frequency about these words, no matter English or Chinese. Otherwise, it should have the synonym and antonym for readers to get the more reference.

Are there any books such as my explaining? Please share its name. Thanks.

Comment: Not super sure what exactly it is that you are looking for....

Comment: Serendipity does not mean 如獲至寶.

Comment: you can look at lyricstranslate.com for 'idioms' with 'Chinese' label. there are some words translated, you can also request a translation there.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly OP wants a list of Chengyu that can be translated as a single English word. Like, 鸡飞狗跳 = chaotic?

Comment: I just review this post. Thanks to @DanielYeung. I get a site for reference those thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the app store, like google play. There are loads of idiom dictionaries you can try.

And like other people commented I don't think your translation of '如獲至寶' is proper. Serendipity is valuable discoveries are made by accident or luck. But '如獲至寶' is finding something which is very valuable, it can be found this thing by accident, but this idiom's main idea is emphasis find something very important. Maybe 机缘巧合 is better.

Comment: More than that, serendipity is what you have when you frequently have happy accidents and good luck.

Comment: So, I think all of you care this and share your opinions. Thanks.